# Host one network and connect to another using a dual-band WiFi adapter

Tags: wireless-networking

Would I be able to separately configure each band of a dual-band WiFi adapter?  That is, connect to a 2.4GHz network and host a 5GHz network at the same time? For example I could use [this WiFi adapter](http://www.netis-systems.com/Home/detail/id/96.html).